# What is a correct use of the !! operator?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-null-safety

I understand what Kotlin's `!!` operator does. I would like to know if there are any use-cases where it is better to use `!!` instead of `?.let` or `?: return`, or some other, safer, null check.

The [Kotlin documentation on null safety](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html) just says that it is for people who love NullPointerExceptions; why would people want those?

I'm mostly just curious as to whether or not there is a use-case for it, where there isn't a better alternative.

Comment: It's useful when a Java function returns an Object, and you know that it can't be null.

Comment: @Aloso for this case can't you use `@NonNull` in java?

Comment: Yes, you can, but many libraries don't do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not everyone is a beginner. Using the exclamation point for this operator helps signify that you better know what you're doing if you do use it.

There are situations where it results in cleaner code. I often see this when working with third-party libraries.

For example, Android's `LiveData.value` is nullable, but if you set the value right when you initialize it, then you know the value can never be null.

```
val myLiveData = MutableLiveData<Float>().apply{ value = 1f }
```

This is a matter of opinion, but I think it would be very noisy to litter every reference to this getter with an unused default:

```
when ((myLiveData.value ?: 1f) > 0f) { /* */ }
```

vs

```
when (myLiveData.value!! > 0f) { /* */ }
```

Personally, if I were using the live data from outside the class, I wouldn't use the double bang because then there's no clear guarantee that it actually has a value set. But from within the class containing it, you can trust yourself to know what you're doing.

Here's another example from Android. When you are working within a PreferenceFragmentCompat, and you need to get a Preference reference, you use `findPreference` which returns null if the preference is not in the hierarchy. If you know that the Preference should be there, then it makes sense to use `!!` because you *want* to see an exception if it actually isn't there. Alternatively, you could use `?: error("missing preference")`, but it's extra code that doesn't really make it any more obvious in the stack trace what went wrong. Or you might be tempted to use `findPreference("x")?.let { //... }` but then it's silently failing when the preference is missing, which is not what you want if you know the preference should be there.

Of course, care should be taken when using `!!`. If your particular PreferenceFragment does some manipulation of Preferences by adding and removing them under various circumstances, it might be more appropriate to use `?.let {/**/} ?: Log.e(...)` just in the off-chance during testing you miss a condition where the preference isn't there when you thought it would be.

Comment: Whenever I'm using live data, I typically just assign it to anther variable first like `val dataVal = myLiveData.value ?: return`  and then use that value, but maybe that is extra. As for the preference, if you  didn't want to assign  a default value I would think showing an error dialog or something would typically be a nicer UX than a crash, no?

Comment: For your first example, that's noisier code with branches of logic it should never reach, and if it does reach that branch, it's silently failing rather than alerting you that you made an error, so it raises the risk of bugs making it into production code. For your second example, it doesn't make sense to show an error dialog in the UI for an error that will never make it to production code. A missing preference in your XML is something you as a programmer would want to discover immediately the first time you compile it so you can discover and fix the bug in the fastest manner possible.

Comment: In certain situations, like the examples I'm using, `?: return` and `?.let` silently hide bugs in the same way as wrapping stuff in a `try {/**/} catch (e: Exception) {} // do nothing`. It's not a good practice to silently mask programming errors.

Answer (score 1):

You would want to throw a NullPointerException whenever a `null` value would indicate that the code itself is incorrect. Just as you might explicitly throw an IllegalArgumentException if an invalid argument indicates that the caller's code is incorrect.

So, the use-case for `!!` is quite similar to the use-case for `if(...) { throw ...; }`, but `!!` is shorter.

If the code is incorrect them you *want* to know about it, and stopping the program immediately with a stack-trace is a good way to (1) inform the programmer about the problem, and (2) provide as much useful information as possible for debugging purposes.